# Make a line break when requesting user input (/P) in batch?

Tags: windows, batch-file, newline, user-input, line-breaks

Is it possible to create a line break after a `set /P` command? I would like the user to be able to type on a new (blank) line instead of next to the existing prompt. For example:

```
set /P test=type now

echo %test%
```

This code simply lets the user type next to the prompt.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you want input on the following line, just use:

```
echo type now
set /p test=
echo %test%
```

The `echo` will output the prompt including the newline, then you just use `set /p` with *no* prompt.

Comment: A very elegant solution. Thank you!

Comment: "Elegant" is my forte. Or was that "quick'n'dirty"? :-)

Comment: Brilliant solution! Thanks.